# Datepicker Widget Showing 20 years only at single time

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi this is the link of my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sN63A/107/)

i am creating date of birth field in form using date picker here is my code below

```
    $( "#pickDate" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(1956, 1 - 1, 1),
  changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true
});
```

it is getting me to the min date but for that i have to click plenty of time as you can see on js fiddle what i want is to that it has to scroll till the last year i have not to click just scroll to the last year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add a `yearRange` option to the datepicker.
Like `yearRange: "1956:2016"`

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6etj6uf5/)

The dropdown shows now the years between 1956 and 2016.

It's in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOptions)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

This will give you previous 100 year dropdown in datepicker at a time. you can change it as your wish.

```
   $("#pickDate" ).datepicker({
      yearRange: "-100:+0",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
```

**UPDATE:** to get the value in php

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="pickDate" value="">
</form>
```

And in php:

```
<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>
```

if the method is post then you can get the value by

```
<?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks this is also good but i have already accepted the answer thanks a lot for your code it is also very simple and effective way

Comment: can you please tell me how to get value of this using php

Comment: See my update. if you like the answer then you click the upvote button. :)
thanks.

Comment: i have tried this code before but it is inserting only month not the whole date

Comment: This should worked fine. Add `dateformat` property and try it, not sure what is the problem in your side. `dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",`.